# Is Jehu a prophet?

Tags: 2-kings

> *<sup>24</sup> Then Jehu drew his bow and shot Joram between the shoulders. The arrow pierced his heart, and he slumped down in his chariot.
>
>
> <sup>25</sup>And Jehu said to Bidkar his officer, “Pick him up and throw him into the field of Naboth the Jezreelite. For remember that when you and I were riding together behind his father Ahab, the LORD lifted up this burden against him: <sup>26</sup>‘As surely as I saw the blood of Naboth and the blood of his sons yesterday, declares the LORD, so will I repay you on this plot of ground, declares the LORD.’ Now then, according to the word of the LORD, pick him up and throw him on the plot of ground.”*
> <sub>`2 Kings 9:24-26 (BSB)`</sub>

Is Jehu a prophet? If not, why does he use the phrase "declares the LORD" in 2 Kings 9:26?

Answer (score 1):

It does not necessarily follow that Jehu was a prophet based on his recollection during a conversation with a colleague of the prophecy of Elijah recorded in 2 Kings 9:24-26.  That prophecy about the doom of the house of Ahab, which Jehu would carry out, is recorded in 1 Kings 21:19-22 & 29.

In the above prophecy, Elijah predicted that dogs would lick his blood in the field of Naboth, but because of Ahab's repentance, the prophecy was transferred to his family and wife as per 1 Kings 21:29.

The above predictions were fulfilled as recorded in 2 Kings 9.